# Problema em Consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Na minha função preciso que se retorne uma list de uma consulta *LINQ*. 
Tenho uma expressão que dependendo de algumas condições ela vai-se adicionando *where* ao retorno dessa função. Segue o codigo:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPotenciaisFornecedoresProdutoFiltro(int id, [FromUriAttribute] List<int> marcas, [FromUriAttribute] List<string> UnidadesFederativas, int dias = 0, int? take = 20, int skip = 0)
    {


        var ofertas = FornecedorProdMarcaCotacaoService.GetAll().Where(p => p.ProdutoMarca.IdProduto == id
                                                       && marcas.Contains(p.ProdutoMarca.IdMarca));

        var compras = ProdutoOrdemCompraService.GetAll()
                                                    .Where(p => p.ProdutoMarca.IdProduto == id
                                                    && marcas.Contains(p.ProdutoMarca.IdMarca));

        if (UnidadesFederativas.Count() > 0)
        {
            ofertas = ofertas.Where(p => p.FornecedorCotacao.Cotacao.RequisicaoEntradaIntegra.Any(c => UnidadesFederativas.Contains(c.IdEstadoFatura)));

            compras = compras.Where(p => UnidadesFederativas.Contains(p.OrdemCompra.IdUnidadeFederativa));
        }
        if (dias > 0)
        {
            DateTime dataDaOperacao = DateTime.Now;
            dataDaOperacao = dataDaOperacao.AddDays(-dias);

            ofertas = ofertas.Where(p => p.FornecedorCotacao.Cotacao.DtCadastro >= dataDaOperacao);

            compras = compras.Where(p => p.OrdemCompra.Cotacao.DtCadastro >= dataDaOperacao);
        }

        ofertas.GroupBy(p => new { p.FornecedorCotacao.IdFornecedor, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.NmPessoa, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.EnderecoFatura.IdUnidadeFederativa })
            .Select(p => new { p.Key.IdFornecedor, p.Key.NmPessoa, p.Key.IdUnidadeFederativa, Count = p.Count() })
            .ToList();

        compras.GroupBy(p => new { p.OrdemCompra.IdFornecedor, p.OrdemCompra.Fornecedor.Pessoa.NmPessoa })
            .Select(p => new { p.Key.IdFornecedor, p.Key.NmPessoa, Count = p.Count() })
            .ToList();

        var query = ofertas.GroupJoin(compras, c => c.FornecedorCotacao.IdFornecedor, c => c.OrdemCompra.IdFornecedor , (o, c) => new { Ofertas = o, Compras = c });
        var count = query.Count();

        var result = query
            .SelectMany(c => c.Compras.DefaultIfEmpty(), (o, c) => new { o.Ofertas.IdFornecedor, NmPessoa = (o.Ofertas.NmPessoa + "-" + o.Ofertas.IdUnidadeFederativa), NrOfertas = o.Ofertas.Count, NrVendas = c == null ? 0 : c.Count })
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.NrVendas)
            .ThenByDescending(c => c.NrOfertas)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take.Value)
            ;

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Items = result, Total = count });

    }
```

Gostaria de saber porque depois do ToList() minha variavel ofertas e compras ainda continuam sendo IQueryable mesmo após o uso do tipo anonimo, teria outro jeito de adicionar as condições?.
[image: IQueriable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando a documentação:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8

Preste atenção nesse detalhe:

**Retornos**

*List
Um List que contém elementos da sequência de entrada.*

Em outras palavras, ao utilizar ToList() ele retorna uma lista, mas veja no seu código:

```
ofertas.GroupBy(p => new { p.FornecedorCotacao.IdFornecedor, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.NmPessoa, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.EnderecoFatura.IdUnidadeFederativa })
            .Select(p => new { p.Key.IdFornecedor, p.Key.NmPessoa, p.Key.IdUnidadeFederativa, Count = p.Count() })
            .ToList();
```

Você está chamando o ToList() e não está atribuindo o resultado a nada, o certo seria:

```
var variavelComRetorno = ofertas.GroupBy(p => new { p.FornecedorCotacao.IdFornecedor, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.NmPessoa, p.FornecedorCotacao.Fornecedor.Pessoa.EnderecoFatura.IdUnidadeFederativa })
                .Select(p => new { p.Key.IdFornecedor, p.Key.NmPessoa, p.Key.IdUnidadeFederativa, Count = p.Count() })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Era isso!! obrigado, só por fim de curiosidade, existe outra maneira que não seja criar outra variável?

Comment: Isso é muito situacional, você poderia por exemplo já colocar esse retorno diretamente onde ele iria ser usado, isso economizaria a variável e deixaria o código mais enxuto, mas as vezes é muito melhor prezar pela legibilidade do que pela economia de código.